# Securely getting information from one view function to another in flask

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am working on implementing two factor authentication in flask where the user chooses one of three ways to authenticate: TOTP with FreeOtp, HOTP by email, and security questions. I am currently doing so with two view functions. One that gets their email and password and another that does the other factor of authentication. If the user enters the correct email and password, I am storing Their email and a timestamp in session variables and sending them to the proper function and for their authentication type like so:

```
if user.otp_secret is not None:
    session['email'] = user.email
    session['email_time'] = datetime.now()
    return redirect(url_for('userbp.token'))
elif user.use_questions:
    session['email'] = user.email
    session['email_time'] = datetime.now()
    return redirect(url_for('userbp.questions'))
```

Then in the next view function I am validating that these session variables are set and that the timestamp is less than five minutes old like so:

```
if 'email_time' not in session or 'email' not in session:
    #Ensure proper sessions were created at first authenitcation
    if 'email' in session:
        del session['email']
    if 'email_time' in session:
        del session['email_time']
    abort(404)
if session['email_time'] < datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=5):
    #Ensure that first authentication took place in the last five minutes
    del session['email']
    del session['email_time']
    flash('The login cookie has expired. Please try again', 'negative')
    return redirect(url_for('userbp.signin'))
user = User.query.filter_by(email=session['email']).first()
if user is None:
    abort(404)
```

From here I proceed to authenticate the user based on their chosen method.

My question is whether or not the flask session variables are secure enough to handle authentication this way, and if not how could I securely pass the user information to the next view.  If a user is able to edit the session variables they would be able to get past the first authentication without needing to know the password. Something else that I have considered is using an encrypted URL token that could be decrypted in the other view. would this be more secure? And if not, how else could I handle it to be more secure.